# How to scrape all the elements in every page

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am currently working on a web scraping project for a car website with Selenium. In the provided code, I am required to navigate to the information page by accessing a link. However, I've observed that when running the code, it seems to iterate only over the first car element in the browser, rather than going through all the cars on the page. Here is my code, how can I fix it and thank you!

```
page_number = 1
all_data = []

while True:
    url = f"{base_url}{page_number}"
    driver.get(url)

    try:
        car = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.versions-item > a').get_attribute('href')
        driver.get(car)

        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'page-title')))

        car_brand_name = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.bloc-title .page-title').text.strip()

        table = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'table')
        rows = table.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'tr')

        data = []
        for row in rows:
            if row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'th'):
                continue
            version = row.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'version').find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'a').text
            price = row.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'price').text
            data.append({'Car Brand': car_brand_name, 'Version': version, 'Price': price})

        all_data.extend(data)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print(f"No more pages. Finished scraping.")
        break
    page_number += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the given code snippet, it appears that your current implementation is navigating to the detail page for the first car found on the listings page, instead of looping through all the cars displayed.

To address this, you need to modify the try...except block inside the main loop, which handles scraping the detailed information for each car. Within this block, you need to replace the hard-coded URL to the car details page with the dynamically generated URL obtained from the HTML's anchor tag (a element) located inside each version listing.

Here's how you can do it:

while True:
url = f"{base_url}{page_number}"
driver.get(url)

```
try:
    car_links = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.versions-item > a')

    # Loop through all the links for each car listed
    for car_link in car_links:

        # Get the URL of the current car and visit its details page
        car_url = car_link.get_attribute('href')
        driver.get(car_url)

        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'page-title')))

        car_brand_name = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.bloc-title .page-title').text.strip()

        table = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'table')
        rows = table.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'tr')

        data = []
        for row in rows:
            if row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'th'):
                continue
            version = row.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'version').find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'a').text
            price = row.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'price').text
            data.append({'Car Brand': car_brand_name, 'Version': version, 'Price': price})

        all_data.extend(data)

    # If all pages have been visited, exit the loop
    if len(driver.find_elements(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Next")) == 0:
        print(f"All pages processed. Exiting scraping.")
        break
    page_number += 1
except NoSuchElementException:
    pass
```

With this modification, your code will now extract all the car data available throughout multiple pages, instead of just one.